# How to fix org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException

Tags: java, web-services, spring, rest, xsd

Here is the snippet of code that is causing the exception :

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate rt
.getForObject(uri, type, vars);
```

The exception is :

> nested exception is
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field "d" (Class com.xsd.myObj), not marked as ignorable

Does this mean there is a field called "d" in the xml document being read that is expected to be in the java/xsd file ? What steps can I take to fix this error ?

Comment: 1) We need to see more of your code (particularly the `com.xsd.myObj` class). 2) Start making a habit of following proper Java naming standards, it helps others help you. 3) Take a look at the [`@JsonIgnoreProperties`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) annotation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means that there are `get` and `set` methods of an object in your class and Jackson is unable to figureout the serialization and deserialization process.

Use `@JsonIgnore` if you don't want the property to be serialized.

If you would like to have this data serialized and deserialized, it could be a problem with polymorphic references. Check [Jackson's Annotation guide](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations) for appropriate usage. You may be interested in `@JsonTypeInfo` in such cases.